# Remove the background of a GtkViewport

Tags: background, gtk, transparency, pygtk, gdk

Is it possible to remove the grey background of a GtkViewport (making the background transparent)?

Comment: Why don't you tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish? It would be much more easier to help you.

Comment: Syntax of my UI: A VBox containing a toolbar and a notebook, who contains in each tab a scrolledwindow with a viewport inside, who contains a GooCanvas drawing area

Answer (score 0):

From my own experimentation, it appears that a GTKViewport has a transparent background by default. This means, then, that the grey background is coming from your GooCanvas drawing area, and not the Viewport.

For creating a transparent background on a GooCanvas, read [THIS TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365842/goocanvas-with-a-transparent-background)

Alternatively, the transparency issue may be in a higher level widget (such as your scrolled window or notebook.)

Comment: How to create a transparent background for GooCanvas? Your link above shows only a question not a answer. Can you let me know?